# How to make jquery setinterval movement in mobile smoother?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, events, setinterval

Sorry for bad english. 
Here's [link](http://hello.404-solution.com/) to site. 
My task is to create site with no scroll. When user clicks to right part of screen car starts to move forward. When it reaches middle of screen - car stops and fixed content-block starts to move in opossite direction. if user moves cursor to left side of screen (while holding mouse button clicked) car should move backward. 
Desktop version works as expected. But mobile version is slow. (it's not exactly slow, **it's not as smooth as desktop** i guess)
What can i do fix this problem?

1. On touchstart event i get event.pageX value to check what part of screen user touched. (so i would know what direction car should move) and store this value in variable "mousePos". Then i call setInterval with movement function
2. On touchend event i clear interval to stop car from moving.
3. On touchmove i will rewrite "mousePos" var with new event.pageX value. For example: user clicked, car starts to move, if user moved cursor to left i will use this var to check direction and turn car back.
4. In mouseMove function i will check car position and decide what action should be done - either move car or move background and i'll check if it reached start of end points

events:

```
    $(document).on('mousedown touchstart', '.mouse-click', function(event){
        clicking = true;
        mousePos = event.pageX;

        if ( event.target.className == 'helper' ) {
            showModal();
        } else {
            moveStuff = setInterval(mouseMove, 1);
        }
    });

    $(document).on('mouseup touchend', function(){
        clicking = false;
        carLights.removeClass('blink');
        clearInterval(moveStuff);
    })

    $(document).on('mousemove touchmove', '.mouse-click', function(event){
        if(clicking == false) {
            return;
        } else {
            mousePos = event.pageX;
        }
    });
```

function:

```
    function mouseMove() {
        let offset = parseInt( mainContent.css('left') );
        let offsetCar = parseInt( car.css('left') );
        if ( mousePos > middleScreen ) {
            carLights.removeClass('blink');
            if ( offset < - ( contentWidth ) ) {
                return;
            } else {
                rotateWheelsForward();
                if ( offsetCar < middleScreen ) {
                    car.css('left', (offsetCar + mouseSpeed) + 'px');
                } else {
                    mainContent.css('left', (offset - mouseSpeed) + 'px');
                }
            }
        } else if ( mousePos < middleScreen ) {
            carLights.addClass('blink');
            if ( offset > 0 ) {
                carLights.removeClass('blink');
                return;
            } else {
                rotateWheelsBackward();
                if ( offsetCar > minCarLeft ) {
                    car.css('left', (offsetCar - mouseSpeed) + 'px');
                } else {
                    mainContent.css('left', (offset + mouseSpeed) + 'px');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So how can i make movement smoother in mobile? (i use iphone 5s safari, but tested in iphone 6, still works bad) 
What changes should i implement to this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use transform rather than position eg: left, top cause thats really affect layer reflow-repaint. Use requestAnimationFrame (wisely) to perform smooth event animation like scroll, mouseup, or any other event.

Then use `will-change: transform;` to element which will "transformed" on the future. This will creates new layer and prepare for the element changes later.

In my case, relative position impact reflow or green flash on the rendering tool chrome. So I prefer use fixed/absolute position to prevent this.

Here's some great article for you to get [Leaner, Meaner, Faster Animations with requestAnimationFrame](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/) and how [to achieving 60 fps animations with css](https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108)

Hope this help ;)

Comment: Thanks, i will read articles and try to rewrite code. If it helps i'll come back later and mark your post as an answer

Comment: I've made some changes. Fun fact: on my phone (iphone 5s) it still not as smooth as it should be, but it works smooth on more modern iphone and android (i've sent link to friends with other phones). I guess i need to make more changes to make it run smoother on older phones, but it works, so thank you)